# Run celery task without workers

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

How to run all celery tasks without workers, I mean call directly?
I can call task with TaskName.run(), but I want to write this in configurations, so how to make it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set the **[CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager)** settings to true, this will force celery not to queue the tasks and run them synchronously in the current process.

If you want to be able to do it per specific task, you can run them with **apply()** or **run()** as you mentioned, instead of running them with **apply_async()** or **delay()**.

So tl;dr:

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
# The following two would do and act the same, processing synchronously
my_task.run() 
my_task.delay()
```

But

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
# These two won't be the same anymore.
my_task.run() # Runs synchronously
my_task.delay() # Passed to the queue and runs Asynchronously, in another process
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you right, you want to call the task synchronously.

Just call the method as normal:

```
TaskName()
```

You only need to use `delay` when you want to send it to the worker.

Comment: ok but how do you get the return value? this is still wrapped in something else by celery

Comment: No. You can still always call a method designated as a task as you would call any other method in python. Celery merely adds the call to a queue that an outside process can execute. If you need to call that task both inside and outside celery (and by outside, I mean synchronously within the execution of a script without polling for a response or something like that, or using any of the asynchronous tools), then just call it as normal. Nothing fancy needed. It is still a method in python able to return values, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to SpiXel 's answer, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933022/celery-not-picking-celery-always-eager-settings), CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER has been renamed to CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER in versions 4.0+. Worked for me with Django 1.11+Celery 4.1.0. So...

```
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False #assync
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True #serial
```